# Superscript not obeying brackets

Tags: brackets, superscripts

I am trying to put in superscript only what is in brackets:

```
(2) Let $\overline{h \circ s}(v) = h(\overline s(c)) = h(c^ {\mathfrak_{U}} )$ when $c$ is a constant. \\

(3) $\overline{h \circ s}(f_{t_1}...f_{t_2}) = h(\overline s(f_{t_1}...f_{t_2})) = h (f^{\mathfrak_{U}} (\overline s(t_1), ..., \overline s(t_2))$ when $f$ is a function.
```

But I keep getting this weirdness. What's going wrong?
[image]

Comment: The answer noting that there is a spurious `_` after `\mathfrak` is correct.  There should have been an error message in your log file.  You should always check the log for error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\mathfrak_{U}` should be `\mathfrak{U}`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/190644)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it is the answer, it just needs the words permuting so that it is an assertion not a question.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!